# Rails Strong Params how to Permit a nested Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, strong-parameters

I have the following params:

```
params={"data"=>
   {"type"=>"book", 
     "id"=>14, 
     "attributes"=> 
          {"id"=>14, 
              "created_at"=>"2022-06-27 21:15:39", 
              "title"=>"sdfdsf",   
              "targeting"=> { "release_times"=>[["4:00", "5:00"], ["5:00", "6:00"]], 
                              "days"=>["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"], 
                              "gender"=>["male", "female"]
                            }
           }
}
```

When I use this, I can get every value but release_times is always null:

When I use this:

`safe_params = params.require(:data).permit( attributes: [:id, :created_at, :title, { targeting: {} }])`

How can I extract the release times value?
I tried doing this

`safe_params = params.require(:data).permit( attributes: [:id, :created_at, :title, { targeting: [:days, :gender, release_times:[]]}])`

But I get the error:

Validation failed: Targeting gender should be a list of values, Targeting days should be a list of values

How can I extract all the values from targeting including the release_times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ruby on Rails API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) states, when using `ActionController::Parameters` you want to declare that a parameter should be an array (list) by mapping it to a empty array. Like you did with  `release_times`.

You should permit `targeting` params with `[days: [], gender: []]` instead of `[:days, :gender]`. This should solve the error.

But even them, `release_times` is an array of arrays, which I believe is not supported at the moment ([there is an old issue for it](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23640)).

One way you could bypass this would be by changing the way you're communicating `release_times`. Using an arrays of hashes instead of nested arrays.

From this:

```rb
"release_times"=>[["4:00", "5:00"], ["5:00", "6:00"]]
```

To this (or something similar):

```rb
"release_times"=>[{"start" => "4:00", "end"=>"5:00"}, {"start" =>"5:00", "end" => "6:00"}]
```

That way, you could do this:

```rb
safe_params = params.require(:data).permit(attributes: [:id, :created_at, :title, { targeting: [days: [], gender: [], release_times: [:start, :end]] }])
```

Exactly how you would implement that is up to you, but I hope it helps.

**Also, there was a typo with release_times.

---

You can do some testing yourself. Open `rails c` and do something like this:

```rb
param = ActionController::Parameters.new("targeting"=> { "release_times"=>[["4:00", "5:00"], ["5:00", "6:00"]]})
param.require(:targeting).permit(release_times: []) # > Doesn't return times.

new_param = ActionController::Parameters.new("targeting"=> { "release_times"=>[{"start" => "4:00", "end"=>"5:00"}, {"start" =>"5:00", "end" => "6:00"}] })
new_param.require(:targeting).permit(release_times: [:start, :end]) # > Return times.
```

---

Just an observation, using `permit!` would work. But as [strong params doc](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) says:

> Extreme care should be taken when using `permit!` as it will allow all
> current and future model attributes to be mass-assigned.

So you could try to `slice` arguments yourself and them `permit!` - but I can't tell you that's the way to go.

Learn more about Mass Assignment Vulnerability [here](https://akshaykhot.com/why-use-strong-parameters-in-rails/).

Comment: Thanks! release_time is still empty. Is it because it's an array of arrays?

Comment: I think we both mispelled "release_time". The final "s" is missing. It should be "release_times". My bad not spotting it :) let me know if it worked!

Comment: thanks! Apologies on the typo on my part. I'm still getting  "release_times"=>[]

Comment: Yes, it seams nested arrays are not supported - I didn't know that. I am updating my asnwer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a alternative for what you're trying to do. I hope it helps :)